# drupal leaflet how change layer name "google-satellite satellite"

Tags: drupal, leaflet, drupal-modules

I install Leaflet and Leaflet More Maps modules in Drupal 7. 
Map looks like on image. How to set custom layers names?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z56bg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found answer thx to RdeBoer.

*These map machine names are the indices of $map_info[....] in file leaflet_more_maps.module.
So you could change these.*

[Original comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2461813#comment-10064840)